# Append element on a list - javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I can't understand why I get undefined on this code. In practice, selecting a value in the first list, I go through a for loop to print a second list corresponding to the values ​​of the selected user. 
The problem is that the item is not hanging because it tells me that it is undefined while it is not so.

```
<html>

<body>
<ol id="ol"></ol>  
<ul id="ol2"></ul> 
<script>

var ol = document.getElementById('ol');
var opn = document.getElementById('ol2'); 

var Assen = document.createElement('li');  

var opts = {
'Assen' : ['1.Dovizioso','2.Dani Pedrosa','3.Valentino Rossi','4.Jorge Lorenzo','5.Stefan Bradl','6.Aleix Espargaro','7.Bradley Smith','8.Pol Espargaro','9.Andrea Iannone','10.Nicky Haiden'],

};

window.onload = function crea()
{

Assen.innerHTML = "Assen";
Assen.setAttribute("onclick","Ch('Assen')");
ol.appendChild(Assen);


}

function Ch(x) 
{
console.log("Funzione attiva!");
var selectedValue = x;

for(i = 0; i < opts[selectedValue].length; i++) 
{
var opt = document.createElement('li');
console.log("opts[selectedValue][i]: " + opts[selectedValue][i]);
opt = opts[selectedValue][i];
console.log("opt.value: " + opt);
document.body.opn.appendChild(opt);
} 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How /where do you get that? Also see the tag descriptions before adding them to you question.

Comment: You'll have to explain how you got the "undefined". Simply opening the html file in Chrome does not return any error in the console and does not display any "undefined" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. You define the value of `opt` to be an element:

```
var opt = document.createElement('li');
```

but then later you overwrite it:

```
opt = opts[selectedValue][i];
```

You should use something like

```
opt.innnerHTML = opts[selectedValue][i];
```

The second problem is that `document.body.opn` is undefined, because you created the variable as `var opn`. So change

```
document.body.opn.appendChild(opt);
```

to

```
opn.appendChild(opt);
```